# Adding localhost 127.0.0.1 to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

A couple times a day, but not in any pattern I can see, I get this in my django logs:

> ERROR Invalid HTTP_HOST header: u'127.0.0.1:9000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

I've tried to match the time of the error to a request in nginx access_log, but I'm not seeing a connection.  I currently have ALLOWED_HOSTS set to `['.mydomain.com']`

- What could be causing these localhost requests?
- Is it common/harmless to add `127.0.0.1` to ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Django 1.8.17
- nginx 1.4.6
- gunicorn 17.5

Comment: nginx acts as a proxy for gunicorn which should only listen on localhost. It shouldn't cause any issues to add it, though it is weird that it doesn't happen all the time. It might happen if the connecting client doesn't send a host header so it defaults (possible) but in other cases the host header is forwarded on.  Do you have a named host `mydomain.com` or can you see your site if you connect by IP only?

Comment: @Cfreak it's a named host.

Comment: @epalm, If you are seeing this error randomly then probably there is configuration problem in your nginx settings. And if you want to add `127.0.01` in Production Server, then I think that is not a good solution.

Comment: Create another loopback  and bind it. A lot service using `lo`, "lo is class A"  so can access any `low level` networks.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled over this question because I had this error. In my case this didn't happen randomly but I still think this could be helpful to people who find this question.

This error also appears in an nginx, gunicorn setup because nginx doesn't pass a host header by default.

To solve this add the following to your nginx configuration:

```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

And you need to add the following to your settings.py

```
    USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

Comment: This helped me with my problem. I was still getting the invalid host error in an nginx environment after trying the default answer to this issue.